# upgrade-assistant analyze a.sln give an error

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, frameworks

I have a solution with many projects that are of ,netframework 4.6.2 and i want to upgraded to 6.0,
this command is applied  upgrade-assistant analyze  a.sln but the below result was noticed:

> [08:11:27 ERR] Could not load project. Please ensure the selected VS
> instance has the correct workloads installed for your projects. If
> Upgrade Assistant selected the incorrect VS version, please pass the
> argument --vs-path with the appropriate path. You can see the Visual
> Studio instances searched by running with the --verbose flag.

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: [Here's a discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant/issues/994) about this error, and i also want to confirm with you that if your computer had only  one VS? and if it is VS 2022?

Comment: @TinyWang I have visual studio 2022 and visual studio code installed  on my PC

Comment: then did you take a try with the suggestion in the error message? `please pass the argument --vs-path with the appropriate path`